# Azure B2C authentication with ServiceStack for an API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, servicestack, azure-ad-b2c

Has anyone got a working sample please with ServiceStack AD authentication for a Azure AD B2C tenant?  We would like to use servicestack but I can only find this old post about Azure B2C and it doesn't have any code sample:

https://forums.servicestack.net/t/azure-ad-b2c-authentication/4655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using one of the [ServiceStack Community Azure Auth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#community-auth-providers) directly is to configure it in your [ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet) or [ASP.NET Identity Server OAuth](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identityserver) App which uses the [ASP.NET Core Identity Auth Adapter](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identity-aspnet#aspnet-core-identity-auth-adapter) to translate Authenticated Identity Auth Requests to an [Authenticated User Session](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) in ServiceStack.

Comment: thanks mythz.  Do you have any sample please to start me off?

Comment: @ossentoo The ASP.NET Identity Auth and IdentityServer docs are for the [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) and [mvcidentityserver](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver) project templates. Have never used Azure AD B2C, but the idea is to configure it with your MVC App then the Adapter would translate the MVC Auth Requests to Authenticated User Sessions in ServiceStack Requests.